# Как безопасно хранить данные для аутентификации (OAuth 2.0)

Tags: flutter, oauth2

У меня есть такой код для получения токена для microsoft graph и он работает, но я хочу сделать приложение безопасным. Насколько я понимаю, в сети вряд-ли можно будет получить доступ к каким-либо конфиденциальным данным по типу пароля или логина, если получать токен через post и по https.
Но как быть с декомпиляцией, возможно ли получить доступ к ClientSecret,ClientId и TenantId через неё? И если можно, то какие есть инструменты для того чтобы этого избежать. С паролем и логином думаю тут всё еще безопасно, поскольку они не константы и их вводит пользователь.

```
  final tenantId = "MY_TENANT_ID";
  final clientId = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
  final clientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET";
  final userNameFromTextField = "USERNAME";
  final passwordFromTextField = "PASSWORD";
  final body = {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": clientId,
    "client_secret": clientSecret,
    "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    "userName": userNameFromTextField,
    "password": passwordFromTextField,
  };
  final response = await http.post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token', body: body);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте представим:

1. Мы вынесли важные для зашиты данные (clientId, clientSecret) на отдельный сервер.
2. Получаем эти данные в зашифрованном виде через get запрос.
3. Расшифровываем их.
4. Делаем OAuth post запрос.

### Мы повысили безопасность?

**Нет**,  обычное приложения для сниффинга трафика предоставит все ваши ключи безопасности в полном объеме. Для этого приложения достаточно установить в систему сертификат (никакой рут и прочие ненужно), т.е. любой пользователь способен прослушать трафик и поймать нужную ему информацию.

*Пока вы пытаетесь защитить приложение от 10% пользователей (которые способны провести декомпиляцию/обфуcкацию), вы даже не предоставляете что у вас есть "дыра в приложении" которой могут воспользоваться 100% пользователей.*

### Итак как нам защитить данные для OAuth?

Поднять сервер для обработки OAuth, отправляя в него только данные пользователя (логин и пароль), в ответ принимать от него токен авторизации. Таким способом вы рискуете только данными пользователями.

Как итог: [Безопасность мобильного OAuth 2.0 от Mail.ru](https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/417031/)